# fizzBuzz откуда берутся undefined?

Tags: javascript

fizzBuzz откуда берутся undefined?

```js
const fizzBuzz = num => {
   for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
      if (num % 3 === 0 && num % 5 === 0) {
        return console.log('fizzbuzz');
      } else if (num % 5 === 0) {
        return console.log('buzz');
      } else if (num % 3 === 0) {
        return console.log('fizz');
      }
   }
   return num;
};


console.log(fizzBuzz(1));
console.log(fizzBuzz(15));
console.log(fizzBuzz(-25));
console.log(fizzBuzz(60));
console.log(fizzBuzz(3));
```

Comment: из  `console.log`

Comment: ``return console.log();``? видимо отсюда и берутся

Comment: ну я и туплю) спасибо)

Comment: Сама функция `console.log()` возвращает `undefined`, то есть ничего не возвращает. А вообще основная ошибка в том, что функцию надо называть `fUzzbuzz`))

Comment: @Leonid нет, конечно же, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz